# Giving a user a secret that the backend can't see

Tags: security, web, redirect, architecture, jwt

Assume the browser-side code is trusted on a website: The frontend is a static website, it's open source, and the loaded files are regularly checksummed. It doesn't send data to the server. For the sake of this argument, just assume the loaded files and scripts are not being maliciously altered by the resource server (Server A).

Now, I'm some other server (Server B) and I want to give the user on this website a secret, for example, an OAuth access token or a JWT, so the user can make requests to Server B from Server A's website. I would prefer to not have the secret be visible to the resource server (Server A).

Is there a way to pass a secret to the user through a redirect or by some other means, without it being shown to Server A?

I can design Server A and Server B, the only security requirement is that Server A should not be able to see the secrets Server B passes to the user of Server A's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the OAuth2 "implicit flow" where the authorization server directly passes the access token to the browser in a hash URL fragment. Hash fragments are never sent to the backend server. However, "implicit flow" is not as secured as "authorization code" flow.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to create browser plugin for solving such kind of problems.
OAuth server may associate token with session id on server side (probably keep it in db). When request with oauth token is received server verifies that the same token is in the session.